# ROWNUM not working for LEFT-OUTER-JOIN

Tags: join, outer-join, rownum

I am using ROWNUM for fetching 999 rows in the following manner:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM PS_MMC_JOBDSSOA_MV JOB, PS_MMC_PERDSSOA_MV PER 
WHERE PER.EMPLID = JOB.EMPLID AND 
PER.ASOFDATE = (SELECT MAX(PER1.ASOFDATE) FROM PS_MMC_PERDSSOA_MV PER1 
WHERE PER1.EMPLID = PER.EMPLID AND PER1.ASOFDATE <= SYSDATE) AND 
JOB.ASOFDATE = (SELECT MAX(JOB1.ASOFDATE) FROM PS_MMC_JOBDSSOA_MV JOB1 
WHERE JOB1.EMPLID = JOB.EMPLID AND JOB1.ASOFDATE <=SYSDATE) AND ROWNUM<1000;
```

I have re wrote the above sql query using left outer join:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM PS_MMC_JOBDSSOA_MV JOB LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_MMC_PERDSSOA_MV PER 
ON (PER.EMPLID = JOB.EMPLID) 
AND PER.ASOFDATE = ((SELECT MAX(PER1.ASOFDATE) FROM PS_MMC_PERDSSOA_MV PER1 WHERE 
PER1.EMPLID = PER.EMPLID AND PER1.ASOFDATE <= SYSDATE) 
AND JOB.ASOFDATE = (SELECT MAX(JOB1.ASOFDATE) FROM PS_MMC_JOBDSSOA_MV JOB1 WHERE 
JOB1.EMPLID = JOB.EMPLID AND JOB1.ASOFDATE <= SYSDATE)) WHERE ROWNUM <1000;
```

ROWNUM is not working with Outer join. I am getting more than 1000 rows.

Could anybody suggest what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this below sql query which is working with ROWNUM

```
SELECT * from (SELECT JOB.DEPTID, JOB.EMPL_STATUS, JOB.LOCATION, JOB.MMC_LOCATION_DESCR, JOB.CITY, JOB."STATE", PER."NAME" FROM
PS_MMC_JOBDSSOA_MV JOB LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_MMC_PERDSSOA_MV PER ON (PER.EMPLID = JOB.EMPLID) 
AND PER.ASOFDATE = (SELECT MAX(PER1.ASOFDATE) FROM PS_MMC_PERDSSOA_MV PER1
WHERE PER1.EMPLID = PER.EMPLID AND PER1.ASOFDATE <= SYSDATE) AND JOB.ASOFDATE = 
(SELECT MAX(JOB1.ASOFDATE) FROM PS_MMC_JOBDSSOA_MV JOB1 WHERE JOB1.EMPLID = JOB.EMPLID AND JOB1.ASOFDATE <= SYSDATE)) 
where ROWNUM <1000
```